# Symmetric Die - Probability

Tags: probability

A symmetric die is tossed 20 times and each time we record whether or not the event {2, 3, 5, 6} has occurred.

Could someone tell me what a "symmetric die" is? The only way the question makes sense to me is if I assume it's a regular six-sided die. Then, I know $P(E)=\frac{4}{6}$. Or is there something about the symmetric die that I'm missing?

Comment: A symmetric die usually means a 'fair' six-faced die. Note that P(E)=4/6 for each seperate throw(!), not all 20 altogether (then it depends what the question actually is).

Comment: @studentmath thanks. I didn't post the questions since I only needed to know whether we were dealing with a six-sided die.

Comment: @andrewsalmon thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption.  A symmetric die is a fair six-sided die.